# How to target li elements in ul using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the text value of a li item within an ul with jquery:

```
     <ul id=list"><li>Milk<button class="check">Check</button></li>
    <li>Bread<button class="check">Check</button></li>
    <li>Eggs<button class="check">Check</button></li></ul>
```

I tried:

```
 $('.check').parent().val();
```

But this didn't work and returned 0 as the value. Basically I want to target the value of li item when the check button is clicked.

Comment: val returns the value and that is 0 in this case. What exactly you want to do with li?

Comment: Side note, missing `"` in `id=list"`

Comment: @AshutoshNigam - I want to get the text inside the li element. I used: $('.check').parent().text(); but this returned the text of both the li and button element. I only the text for the li element.

Comment: @Abdi added the code as answer, check if this is what you want?

Comment: @Nima - yes it has worked - I was in the middle of doing the same thing! Thanks

Comment: @Abdi Glad to help. I was in the same situation recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text()` instead of `val()`, and although it will include the value of the button, we can remove it with `split()` and `join()`. Just to obtain the value inside of the clicked parent.

```js
$('.check').on("click", function () {
    var val = $(this).parent().text().split("Check").join("");
    alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li>Milk
        <button class="check">Check</button>
    </li>
    <li>Bread
        <button class="check">Check</button>
    </li>
    <li>Eggs
        <button class="check">Check</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<li>` items don't actually have a value as understood by jquery/javascript. Instead, they just have text within the list item. Furthermore, if you just try to grab the `.text()` within the `<li>` you'll also get the text from the button itself because it's within the list item.

There's a couple different approaches you could take. Wrap the text within a `<span>` and then use jquery to find that after clicking on the button. Or you could simply assign a value as a data attribute to the list item itself and then use jquery grab that.

```
<li data-val="eggs">Eggs
    <button class="check-val">Check</button>
</li>

$(".check-val").on("click", function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('data-val'));
});
```

See this fiddle which shows the different approaches: http://jsfiddle.net/mark47/uyzmbmwt/

Answer (score 1):

On click of the button you get the label:

```
$(".check").on("click",function(){
        alert ($(this).parent().children("label").text());
    });
```

Comment: @Abdi happy to be of help, could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you say value, perhaps you mean the text inside the li?  If so, you could get rid of the button, assign its class to the li itself, and just click on the text:

```
$('.check').click(function () {
    alert($(this).html();
});
```

You could style it to look like a button.  Or, if you want to keep the button, you could give it an id and grab that:

```
$('.check').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.check').click(function(){ var value = $(this).parent().first().children().html();})
```